# How do I make my program find the record store?

Tags: java, java-me, midp, rms

I've just started out with J2ME and record stores. This seems to be the proper way to open a record store named "foo", *not* creating a new one:

```
RecordStore.openRecordStore("foo", false)
```

Fine, I get that. But where do I put the actual file for my program to find it?  I'm using NetBeans 7.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to know where the file is, J2Me put the file somewhere, if the store already exists, you can open it, or use true in the open method to create it if it doesn't exist.

```
RecordStore rs = RecordStore.openRecordStore("foo", true);
```

to write to your recordstore, use this :

```
String s = "your-data";
byte[] rec = s.getBytes();
rs.addRecord(rec, 0, rec.length);
```

to read :

```
RecordEnumeration re = rs.enumerateRecords(null, null, false);
while (re.hasNextElement()){
   String s = new String(re.nextRecord());
}
```

and close your recordStore after each operation:

```
 rs.closeRecordStore();
```

---

**update**

> how do I read the contents of the file?

read your existing file as a normal file with :

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/foo");
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
int chars;
while ((chars = is.read()) != -1)
    sb.append((char) chars);
String str = new String(String.valueOf(sb).getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

and write the string to your recordStore with the code above.

Comment: I already have a file which is a record store. Where do I put it for Java to find it?

Comment: you can't, copy the content of your file to the recordStore by writing it with addrecord.